# Antenna matching using L-sections does not always yield a "matched" solution

Tags: impedance-matching

I created a program to compute the component values of a T network to match a reactive load (R+jX) to a 50 ohm source, based on the procedure outlined by M. Walter Maxwell in  his book "Reflections".  I then verify the match using LTSpice, expecting to see half the input amplitude, and the current being in phase with the voltage if the match is perfect.  This only seems to work sometimes, and I am still trying to understand what it is about the impedance of the load or the target Q value I design the network for that determines whether a "good" match is indeed obtained.

Below is the approach and program used:

[image: t-network_diagram]

Rs1 is the load resistance, while the load reactance is absorbed into Xs1.   The procedure uses the following equations to compute the reactances of the L-sections:

[image: equations]

Rv is a virtual version of the the matched parallel Rp used as the load for "section 2" -- it is not ultimately in the matching network.  It should be greater than both Rs1 and the source impedance, so Q must be selected to ensure this.

I start with the antenna load, and select a Q for that section.  I enter the source impedance, and the resonant frequency, and the program calculates all the reactances and determines the corresponding L-C values.  The reactances can be inductive or capacitive, but the sections must be L-C or C-L, never L-L or C-C.

Taking for example a match to a load with impedance 9.84 +j120 (at 40.68MHz), and Q=100, the program yields: L1 = 3.4uH, Ls2=8.7u, Cp =5.7pf.

When I verify these on LTSpice, [image: ltspice_fix]

I expect the voltage at Vmatch to be half the input voltage (since Rs =Rl = 50), and  the current to be in phase.  However, this is what I get:
[image]

Vmatch is greater than expected, and the current is not in phase with Vmatch.

However, I believe the code to be correct because I do get working matches for other loads and Q.  If I match a 12+j20 load, with a Q=5 at 3.5Mhz to 50ohms, I get:
Ls1 = 1.8u
Ls2=5.2u
Cp=1.06nf

When I simulate these values, I get the expected results:
[image]

**What could be the reason the matching calculations work in some cases but not others?**
Here's the code I wrote for reference:

```
# Matching Network
# 10/13/2020

import numpy as np
import re

# Series-Parallel equivalent circuit equations
# Q = Xs/Rs = Rp/Xp
# RP=Rs(Q^2+1)
# Rp/Rs=Q^2 +1
# Q = sqrt(Rp/Rs-1) 
# Xs = Q*Rs
# Rs = Rp/(Q^2+1)
# Xp = Rp/Q


#T-Network
ttype=int(input('Enter 1 for L-C-L or 2 for C-L-C T-Network: '))
q1 =float(input('Enter Q1:\n'))
rload = float(input('Enter Load Resistance: '))
xload = float(input('Enter Load Reactance (negative for capacitive, pos for inductive: '))
rsrc  = float(input('Enter Source Resistance: '))
f0 = float(input('Enter Resonant frequency:  '))

#f0 = 40.68e6
#q1 = 100
#rload = 9.838
#xload = 2*np.pi*f0*469.91e-9
#rsrc = 50

rs2=rsrc
rpv = rload*(q1**2+1)
q2 = np.sqrt(rpv/rs2 - 1)
print('Q2 = ', q2)
print('rpv = ',rpv)

if(ttype ==1):
    print("I'm here")
    xs1 = q1*rload - xload
    xp1 = -rpv/q1
    xs2 = q2*rs2
    xp2 = -rpv/q2
else:
    xs1 = -q1*rload - xload
    xp1 = rpv/q1
    xs2 = -q2*rs2
    xp2 = rpv/q2

print('xs1 = ',xs1)
print('xp1 = ',xp1)
print('xs2 = ',xs2)
print('xp2 = ',xp2)


xpcomb= xp1*xp2/(xp1+xp2)
print('xpcomb = ', xpcomb)

if(ttype==1):
    Ls1 = xs1/(2*np.pi*f0)
    Ls2 = xs2/(2*np.pi*f0)
    print('f0 = ',f0)
    print('xpcomb =  ',xpcomb)
    Cp = 1/(2*np.pi*f0*xpcomb)

    print('\nLs1 = ', Ls1)
    print('Ls2 = ', Ls2)
    print('Cp = ', Cp)
    
else:
    Cs1 = 1/(2*np.pi*f0*xs1)
    Cs2 = 1/(xs2*2*np.pi*f0)
    Lp = xpcomb/(2*np.pi*f0)

    print('\nCs1 = ', Cs1)
    print('Cs2 = ', Cs2)
    print('Lp  = ', Lp)
```

Comment: Do an AC plot to see where it does line up. What did Rv calculate as?

Comment: I did;  lower -around 39.5MHz.  Rv ~= 98.4k

Comment: Yeah I thought 98.4 k because of the Q of 100. Unfortunately my website calculators don't do the LCL T section but, when I went on my L-pad calculator I reckoned something was wrong in your calculations somewhere. There are other sites that might confirm things. Maybe a rounding error somewhere? If I plug those numbers into [my L-pad calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html) I get 3.9758 pF and 3.849 uH for the final L-pad.